# jquery submit() on alertify confirm not firing

Tags: jquery, submit, confirm, alertify

Can someone tell me why is my submit() not firing?

If I try do it removing the
alertify.confirm() just with my submit() it works.

```
$('.myBtn').click(function(){
    alertify.confirm("Confirmation",function(e){
        if(e){
            $(this).closest('form').submit();
        }else{
             alertify.error('Nope');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please add you code snippet ?

Comment: Is your button a button button, a submit button, or just a button.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most similar way that I found to do it as I wanted.
$('.myBtn') is a normal button inside a form. 
I call it with a class because they are a set of forms.

```
$('.myBtn').click(function(){
$btn = $(this);
alertify.confirm("Confirmation",function(e){
    if(e){
        $btn.closest('form').submit();
    }else{
         alertify.error('Nope');
    }
});
```

});